# Kyoto TreeDB insertion slows down after 100 million records

Tags: kyotocabinet

I am inserting records in Kyoto TreeDB. 
The key is simply a counter which I increment and the value is fixed.

After 100 million records, insertion gradually keeps slowing down.
Has anyone tried to insert more records in Kyoto Cabinet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting hash collisions. It will put records into an overflow area if that happens. I believe that degenerates to a searched list.

Comment: I don't see any option to tune TreeDB for higher number of records. I want to insert 1 billion records.

Answer (score 0):

HashDB is more memory efficient than TreeDB. Since you are using TreeDB you may want to tinker with the cache option to keep insertions fast.

Comment: ok. I will see into that. But I want to insert 1 billion records & in HashDB when I increase the bucket size to 2 billion, it takes a lot of time to insert.

Answer (score 0):

Did you increase bnum and msiz accordingly?

I had very poor insert performance with a too low msiz value.